# Using Unreal Engine 5 PCG graph to spawn terrain altering blueprint actors causing loop

Tags: procedural-generation, unreal-5

I am using a PCG graph to spawn in actors, which are blueprint stamps for the terrain height map. I believe the issue I am facing is that when the blueprints are spawned, they alter the terrain, which prompts the PCG graph to regenerate.

My PCG graph is pretty simple:

[image]

Is there a way to set all points to 0 on the global z-axis? Or a way to only sample the pre-altered terrain?

Answer (score 1):

Yah mate ran into the same problem.  Try using a WorldRayHitQuery instead of the Input node or Get Landscape Data node.

When the landscape updates it doesn't re-dirty the hit query so your graph won't flicker.